# IOS how to remove notification from notification center while app is terminated by user

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios13

I was wondering how does WhatsApp remove notifications from notification center(when read from web as example) while app is terminated by user

- I am using silent notification but it's not starting app if closed by user,
- for voip notification in ios13 we must respond to pushkit notification by reporting new call otherwise the app will crash

Comment: Did you read through https://stackoverflow.com/q/55646178/2442804 ?

Comment: yes i read it it's not working if the app is terminated but the user

Comment: Do you have a badge count set and tried to push a silent notification with badge count 0 afterwards?

Comment: yes i have a badge count set but i didn't try silent notification with badge 0  (i don't know if the silent notification will be delivered if the app is killed)

Comment: i tried to set badge 0 notification it works to remove all notifications but is there away to remove a notification not all of them

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can find some clues in `UNUserNotificationCenter.h` :

```
- (void)removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray<NSString *> *)identifiers __API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
- (void)removeAllDeliveredNotifications __API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
```

Comment: the issue is not how remove notfication but silent notification is not delivered when app is killed that is the issue so there is no way to remove the notification while the app is killed by the user